# Generating consecutive bitmaps with wxPython trouble

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Well, while I don't consider myself an experienced programmer, especially when it comes to multimedia applications, I had to do this image viewer sort of a program that displays images fullscreen, and the images change when the users press <- or -> arrows.

The general idea was to make a listbox where all the images contained in a certain folder (imgs) are shown, and when someone does double click or hits RETURN a new, fullscreen frame is generated containing, at first, the image selected in the listbox but after the user hits the arrows the images change in conecutive order, just like in a regular image viewer.

At the beginning, when the first 15 - 20 images are generated, everything goes well, after that, although the program still works an intermediary, very unpleasant and highly unwanted, effect appears between image generations, where basically some images that got generated previously are displayed quickly on the screen and after this the right, consecutive image appears. On the first apparitions the effect is barelly noticeble, but after a while it takes longer and longer between generations.

Here's the code that runs when someone does double click on a listbox entry:

```
def lbclick(self, eve):
    frm = wx.Frame(None, -1, '')
    frm.ShowFullScreen(True)
    self.sel = self.lstb.GetSelection() # getting the selection from the listbox
    def pressk(eve):
        keys = eve.GetKeyCode()
        if keys == wx.WXK_LEFT:
            self.sel = self.sel - 1
            if self.sel < 0:
                self.sel = len(self.chk) - 1
            imgs() # invocking the function made for displaying fullscreen images when left arrow key is pressed
        elif keys == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
            self.sel = self.sel + 1
            if self.sel > len(self.chk) - 1:
               self.sel = 0
            imgs() # doing the same for the right arrow 
       elif keys == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            frm.Destroy()       
       eve.Skip()
    frm.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, pressk)
    def imgs(): # building the function
        imgsl = self.chk[self.sel]
        itm = wx.Image(str('imgs/{0}'.format(imgsl)), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap() # obtaining the name of the image stored in the list          self.chk
        mar = itm.Size   # Because not all images are landscaped I had to figure a method to rescale them after height dimension, which is common to all images
        frsz = frm.GetSize()
        marx = float(mar[0])
        mary = float(mar[1])
        val = frsz[1] / mary
        vsize = int(mary * val)
        hsize = int(marx * val)
        panl = wx.Panel(frm, -1, size = (hsize, vsize), pos = (frsz[0] / 2 -  hsize / 2, 0)) # making a panel container
        panl.SetBackgroundColour('#000000')
        imag = wx.Image(str('imgs/{0}'.format(imgsl)), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).Scale(hsize, vsize, quality = wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_NORMAL).ConvertToBitmap()
        def destr(eve): # unprofessionaly trying to destroy the panel container when a new image is generated hopeing the unvanted effect, with previous generated images will disappear. But it doesn't.
            keycd = eve.GetKeyCode()
            if keycd == wx.WXK_LEFT or keycd == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
                try:
                    panl.Destroy()
                except:
                    pass
            eve.Skip()
        panl.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, destr) # the end of my futile tries
        if vsize > hsize: # if the image is portrait instead of landscaped I have to put a black image as a container, otherwise in the background the previous image will remain, even if I use Refresh() on the container (the black bitmap named fundal)
            intermed = wx.Image('./res/null.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).Scale(frsz[0], frsz[1]).ConvertToBitmap()
            fundal = wx.StaticBitmap(frm, 101, intermed)
            stimag = wx.StaticBitmap(fundal, -1, imag, size = (hsize, vsize), pos = (frsz[0] / 2 -  hsize / 2, 0))
            fundal.Refresh()
            stimag.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip('Esc = exits fullscreen\n<- -> arrows = quick navigation'))
            def destr(eve): # the same lame attempt to destroy the container in the portarit images situation
                keycd = eve.GetKeyCode()
                if keycd == wx.WXK_LEFT or keycd == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
                    try:
                        fundal.Destroy()
                    except:
                        pass
                eve.Skip()
            frm.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, destr)
        else: # the case when the images are landscape
            stimag = wx.StaticBitmap(panl, -1, imag)
            stimag.Refresh()
            stimag.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip('Esc = exits fullscreen\n<- -> arrows = quick navigation'))
    imgs() # invocking the function imgs for the situation when someone does double click
    frm.Center()
    frm.Show(True)
```

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Added later:

The catch is I'm trying to do an autorun presentation for a DVD with lots of images on it. Anyway it's not necessarely to make the above piece of code work properly if there are any other options. I've already tried to use windows image viewer, but strangely enough it doesn't recognizes relative paths and when I do this

```
path = os.getcwd() # getting the path of the current working directory
sel = listbox.GetSelection() # geting the value of the current selection from the list box
imgname = memlist[sel] # retrieving the name of the images stored in a list, using the listbox selection, that uses as choices the same list
os.popen(str('rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen {0}/imgsdir/{1}'.format(path, imgname))) # oepning the images up with bloody windows image viewer
```

it opens the images only when my program is on the hard disk, if it's on a CD / image drive it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's an image viewer included with the wxPython demo package. I also wrote a really simple one [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/). Either one should help you in your journey. I suspect that you're not reusing your panels/frames and instead you're seeing old ones that were never properly destroyed.